# Coefficients of universal Schubert polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus

Let $e_i^j$ be the elementary symmetric polynomial in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_j$. Then the ordinary Schubert polynomial has an expansion of the form
$$S_u(x)=\sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n}{a^{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n}_ue_{i_1}^1\cdots e_{i_n}^n}$$
where the $a_u^{i_1,\ldots,i_n}$ are integers. We can interpret $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ as the code of a unique permutation, so we can rewrite this as
$$S_u(x)=\sum_{v\in S_{\infty}}{a_{u}^ve_v}$$
Taking the inverse of the matrix $(a_u^v)$ gives us a matrix $(c_u^v)$ with nonnegative entries, and
$$S_{uw_0}(x)=\sum_{v}{c_u^vx_v}$$
The coefficients $c_u^v$ are well understood (they can be expressed in terms of Bruhat paths, RC graphs, etc.). Somehow, though, the $a_u^v$ seem far more important. The universal Schubert polynomials and quantum Schubert polynomials use these coefficients in their definition, replacing the elementary monomials with something else. Have the $a_u^v$ been studied in and of themselves?

Comment: The following paper seems relevant: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0001870898917303/1-s2.0-S0001870898917303-main.pdf?_tid=f6d13974-8c16-11e5-8ab1-00000aacb362&acdnat=1447646776_c024f8eb0bfabe981616499b2dec2921

Comment: @Suvrit That it most certainly is, thanks.

Comment: I found a "positive" (non-cancellative) formula for $a_u^v$ when $u$ is a simple cycle (more generally, it's a "Pieri formula" for the product $x_i^kS_w(x)$).